# how to write an event for shockWave flash object

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, axshockwaveflash

Is there any way to write click event for shockWave flash object?

Comment: no I want to use it in a windowsForm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is no way of doing this without modifing the flash application (swf) or at least wrapping it in a new one. Once you are able to capture the click event in Flash, you can use any of the communication schemes available for *flash+a host application*. You could use in this scenario:
    -[FS Command](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/package.html) ("[Sending Data from a Flash Movie to the Hosting C# Application](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/fscommand.aspx)" in CodeProject)
    -[External Interface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6) ("[Fun with C# and the Flash Player 8 External API](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/flashexternalapi.aspx)" also in CodeProject)

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
public abstract partial class SetWindowLongForm : Form
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr RealChildWindowFromPoint(IntPtr hwndParent, POINT ptParentClientCoords);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr ChildWindowFromPoint(IntPtr hWndParent, POINT Point);

    [DllImport("User32.Dll", EntryPoint = "PostMessageA")]
    public static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint msg, int wParam, int lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, IntPtr dwNewLong);

    [DllImport("user32")]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, WindowProcedure newProc);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr DefWindowProc(IntPtr hWnd, int uMsg, int wParam, int lParam);

    [DllImport("user32")]
    private static extern IntPtr CallWindowProc(IntPtr lpPrevWndFunc, IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool ReleaseCapture();

    private delegate IntPtr WindowProcedure(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct POINT
    {
        public int X;
        public int Y;

        public POINT(int x, int y)
        {
            this.X = x;
            this.Y = y;
        }

        public POINT(System.Drawing.Point pt) : this(pt.X, pt.Y) { }

        public static implicit operator System.Drawing.Point(POINT p)
        {
            return new System.Drawing.Point(p.X, p.Y);
        }

        public static implicit operator POINT(System.Drawing.Point p)
        {
            return new POINT(p.X, p.Y);
        }
    }

    private WindowProcedure newWindowProcedure = null;
    private IntPtr oldWindowProcedure = IntPtr.Zero;
    private IntPtr HookedWindowHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
    private const int GWL_WNDPROC = -4;
    private Timer SetWindowLongTimer;

    protected abstract void onShockWaveClick();
    protected abstract void onShockWaveBorderLineMouseMove(int x, int y);

    public SetWindowLongForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        SetWindowLongTimer = new Timer();
        SetWindowLongTimer.Interval = 1000;
        SetWindowLongTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(SetWindowLongTimer_Tick);
        SetWindowLongTimer.Start();
    }
    private void SetWindowLongTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetWindowLongTimer.Stop();
        SetWindowLongTimer.Tick -= new EventHandler(SetWindowLongTimer_Tick);
        try
        {
            Control shockerHandle = Controls.OfType<AxShockwaveFlashObjects.AxShockwaveFlash>().FirstOrDefault();
            if (shockerHandle == null) return;
            ChangeShockWaveWindowProcedure(shockerHandle.Handle);
        }
        catch { }
    }
    protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnClosed(e);
        RevertShockWaveWindowProcedure();
    }
    private void ChangeShockWaveWindowProcedure(IntPtr theHandle)
    {
        if (theHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            HookedWindowHandle = theHandle;
            newWindowProcedure = new WindowProcedure(newWindowProc);
            oldWindowProcedure = SetWindowLong(HookedWindowHandle, GWL_WNDPROC, newWindowProcedure);
        }
    }
    private void RevertShockWaveWindowProcedure()
    {
        if (HookedWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            SetWindowLong(HookedWindowHandle, GWL_WNDPROC, oldWindowProcedure);
            HookedWindowHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
        }
    }
    private IntPtr newWindowProc(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        const int WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x0200;
        const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201;
        switch (Msg)
        {
            case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
                {
                    //Control ctrlTmp = Control.FromHandle(hWnd);
                    int x = lParam.ToInt32() & 0xffff;
                    int y = lParam.ToInt32() >> 16;
                    onShockWaveBorderLineMouseMove(x, y);
                    break;
                }
            case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
                ReleaseCapture();
                Point pt = new Point(MousePosition.X, MousePosition.Y);
                Control ctrl = Control.FromHandle(hWnd); // Controls.OfType<AxShockwaveFlashObjects.AxShockwaveFlash>().FirstOrDefault();
                pt = ctrl.PointToClient(pt);
                IntPtr ax = ctrl.Handle;
                Rectangle r = new Rectangle(0, 0, ctrl.Width, ctrl.Height);
                IntPtr isTHis = ChildWindowFromPoint(Handle, new POINT(pt)); //where was the mouse pressed
                if (r.Contains(pt))
                {
                    onShockWaveClick();
                }
                ReleaseCapture();
                break;
        }
        return CallWindowProc(oldWindowProcedure, hWnd, Msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        //if (m.Msg == 528)
        //{
        //    IntPtr lbutDown = new IntPtr(0x0201);
        //    if (m.WParam == lbutDown)
        //    {
        //        Point pt = new Point(MousePosition.X, MousePosition.Y);
        //        pt = axShockwaveFlash1.PointToClient(pt);
        //        IntPtr ax = axShockwaveFlash1.Handle;
        //        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(0, 0, axShockwaveFlash1.Width, axShockwaveFlash1.Height);
        //        IntPtr isTHis = ChildWindowFromPoint(Handle, new POINT(pt));
        //        if (r.Contains(pt))
        //        {
        //            int k = 90;
        //            k += 90;
        //        }
        //    }
        //}
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

Derive your Form from this class, and insert this code in your derived class

```
protected override void onShockWaveClick()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Is this it?\n In Main Form", "AxSHockWave Message");
    }
    protected override void onShockWaveBorderLineMouseMove(int x, int y)
    {
        if (y >= axShockwaveFlash1.Height - 20)
        {
            Text = "Borderline x=" + x.ToString() + " , y = " + y.ToString() + ", ht= " + axShockwaveFlash1.Height;
        }
        else
        {
            Text = "Moving x=" + x.ToString() + " , y = " + y.ToString() + ", ht= " + axShockwaveFlash1.Height;
        }
    }
```

everything else will be taken care by the base class