# flash and c# windows apllication integration

Tags: c#, flash-cs4

i have created one flash(.swf) file havin 3 text field (dynamic data) and imported in c# windows application using axshockwave object,how to get value of text field from flash to c# windows application to perform calculation from data inserted in text field?

Comment: [how to write an event for shockWave flash object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984636/how-to-write-an-event-for-shockwave-flash-object)

Comment: actually i used fscommand for this purpose but it is not helping me ..i need to catch the value inserted in textbox of flash form in c# windows application so that i can calculate it and throw it back to flash to display...

Comment: [Communicate betwen C# and an embeded Flash application](http://blog.another-d-mention.ro/programming/communicate-betwen-c-and-an-embeded-flash-application/)